# Update the timestamp columns of a SQL Server Filetable programatically?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, filetable

I have a filetable in a SQL Server database, with both T-SQL and Windows Share I/O access enabled.

I have a C# WinForms front end that loads files from this filetable, modifies and updates them back into the filetable. This is all working fine, and I can verify the file contents are getting updated correctly by both the changing file_stream binary as viewed directly in SSMS, and by viewing the files through the Windows Filetable share.

However, the `creation_time`, `last_write_time` and `last_access_time` columns of the filetable are not updated automatically **when updating the files using T-SQL.**

I've dug through the MSDN pages, which state the columns are 'calculated automatically', but this appears not to be the case.

Updating the files by simply opening them from the share, editing and saving them, **does** cause the columns to automatically update.

My stored procedure for updating the file_stream binary column is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateFileBinary] 

    @fileId uniqueidentifier,
    @fileBinary VARBINARY(MAX)

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE files
    SET file_stream = @fileBinary
    WHERE stream_id = @fileId;
END
```

I  have seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/access-filetables-with-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) that "Describes how Transact-SQL data manipulation language (DML) commands work with FileTables........ Updates can be made to the FILESTREAM data in the file_stream column without affecting any of the other columns, including the timestamps."

That says **can** be made, but how do we do a T-SQL update and **do** update those columns?

Comment: Did you enable filestream for file I/O streaming access?

Comment: Yes, I can successfully add/remove/update files from the Filetable either via the Windows share/API, and T-SQL.